# Problem while converting html code to plain text

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to convert the HTML code to a plain text as a paragraph, the HTML code will be compose from CKEDITOR. Then i use `strip_tags()` and `html_entity_decode()` to convert the string to the normal paragraph. With the normal sentences it's work fine, but when in your sentences content some sign as the acronym such as `'`, it will not be converted. I don't know how to make sense this problem. Here is an example:

*Input CKEDITOR:

```
This is a notification, but don't worry about this
```

*PHP:

```
$message = '<p>This is a notification, but don&#39;t worry about this.</p>';
$message = strip_tags($message);
$message = html_entity_decode($message);
$message = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]+; | \r|\n/i","",$message);
echo $message;
```

*Output:

```
This is a notification, but don&#39;t worry about this.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `html_entity_decode` only converts double quotes and not single quotes.  Use the following to convert both:

```
$message = html_entity_decode($message, ENT_QUOTES);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php